# Why I cannot merge the two files, with left_join, in R?

Tags: r, left-join, tidyverse

I am trying to link two files with left join, in R. I do not get the output I need.

Here is an example of two files:

here is file_1:

And when I do  a left_join in R, I do not get what I want. Here is the code:

```
minap_piv_na_stemi_nstemi <- left_join(file_1, file_2)
```

As you can see in the last line, `Rochdale Infirmary` should be populated with the `provider_name` and `trust_code`. This is not happening? Can someone help ?

Comment: The two files you gave are identical. Can you edit one of them so we can help?

Comment: @MonJeanJean  amended the mistake. Thank you for flagging up

Comment: The issue is that your df are joined by both name and code, i.e. all cols present in both dfs. And e.g. Rochdale Infirmary has a code in file_1 but it's NA in file_2. Try with left_join(file_1, file_2, by = "hospital_name")

Comment: it does not populate where I want, it adds another column 'provide_name.y', whilst I want to see only one column - 'provide_name', and the same with trust_code, I get trust_code.x, and trust_code.y, whilst with left_join, i am hoping to get only trust_code, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `left_join` to join by `hospital_name`. Use e.g. `coalesce` to fill in the missing information for `trust_code` and `provider_name`. Get rid of the `.x` and `.y` columns:

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(file_1, file_2, by = "hospital_name") %>% 
  mutate(trust_code = coalesce(trust_code.x, trust_code.y),
         provider_name = coalesce(provider_name.x, provider_name.y)) %>% 
  select(-ends_with(".x"), -ends_with(".y"))
#> # A tibble: 182 x 3
#>    hospital_name           trust_code provider_name                             
#>    <chr>                   <chr>      <chr>                                     
#>  1 Addenbrooke's Hospital  RGT        Cambridge University Hospitals NHS Founda…
#>  2 Royal Albert Edward In… RRF        Wrightington, Wigan and Leigh NHS Foundat…
#>  3 Airedale General Hospi… RCF        Airedale NHS Trust                        
#>  4 Wycombe Hospital        RXQ        Buckinghamshire Healthcare NHS Trust      
#>  5 Barnsley Hospital       RFF        Barnsley Hospital NHS Foundation Trust    
#>  6 Basildon Hospital       RDD        Basildon and Thurrock University Hospital…
#>  7 Royal United Hospital … RD1        Royal United Hospital Bath NHS Trust      
#>  8 Bedford Hospital        RC1        Bedford Hospital NHS Trust                
#>  9 Broomfield Hospital     RQ8        Mid Essex Hospital Services NHS Trust     
#> 10 Rochdale Infirmary      RW6        Pennine Acute Hospitals NHS Trust         
#> # … with 172 more rows
```

Comment: thank you, it worked so nicely. coalesce is a new function to me.

Comment: I knew coalesce quite some time, but this was the first time I used it. :D